# extract subsystem from a simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to extract a subsystem from existing model.
So I have tried firstofall the following command:

`open_system('test_extraaction');
newmodel = slvnvextract('test_extraaction/sub', true);`

but it didn't work I think this command just work just with existing subsystem
because the error is
??? Error using ==> slvnvextract at 46
Invalid usage of slvnvextract. First argument must specify an Atomic Subsystem or an Atomic Subchart.

then i have tried the new_system function as it's defined

> new_system(sys, model, subsystem_path)

```
load_system('test_extraaction')
 new_system('new','Model','test_extraaction/sub')
```

but it didn't work also!!
the error is:
??? The only control port allowed at the root level of a block diagram is a trigger port.

can you help please and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the first error message suggests, you can only use `slvnvextract` with atomic subsystems, so if you want to do it this way, you will need to make your subystem atomic.

The second approach appears the right way to do what you want. The error message suggests that you have a control port other than a trigger port in the subystem you copying to your new model. This is not allowed at the root level of a model. Can you post a screenshot of the subsystem `test_extraaction/sub`?

Comment: i resolved the problem and it's as you have said about the trigger port so the solution that i have find it is to delete the trigger port before copieng to the new model.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it helped so that other users with similar problems can more easily find a solution.